# Images aren't displaying on github pages

Tags: javascript, image, github

I'm using github pages to host a practice website.  I've built a simple JS slideshow and the images in the slideshow are not displaying.  When I use Atom live server to display the site, the images and slideshow work fine. When using github pages I inspected the active slideshow and it is moving through the image array fine as I can see the `src` attribute changing the way it should so I know the code is looping through the array properly.  I'm not sure what is wrong.

the relevant JavaScript

```
const image = [
  '../images/karakoy-1.jpg',
  '../images/karakoy-2.jpg',
  '../images/karakoy-3.jpg',
  '../images/karakoy-4.jpg',
  '../images/karakoy-5.jpg',
];
let i = 0;
const imageContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-image');
const time = 3000;

function changeSlide() {
  imageContainer[0].src = image[i];
  if (i < image.length - 1) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }

  setTimeout('changeSlide()', time);
}

changeSlide();
```

I've also checked all the spelling and capitilization on the filenames.  Everything checks out.  Like I said,  when I use Atom live server everything works fine.

UPDATE   https://jtc10.github.io/Arcadia-Restaurant/

Here is a link to the page.  Click the "reservations" link.  The slideshow  is on that page.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could give us a link to the github page that's misbehaving.  It's probably something to do with the resource paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely an issue resolving relative paths between your local and live servers.

The requests with the relative paths are all returning 404 Not Found:

[image]

I prefer to use the full path from root instead. This takes the ambiguity out of the situation.

```
const image = [
    '/images/karakoy-1.jpg',
    '/images/karakoy-2.jpg',
    '/images/karakoy-3.jpg',
    '/images/karakoy-4.jpg',
    '/images/karakoy-5.jpg',
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It tries to load `https://jtc10.github.io/images/karakoy-2.jpg` which don't exist, remove the `../` from the image path.